# Is there a resolution limitation for the appsrc module in Gstreamer when working with custom-made image sensors?

Tags: c++, linux, computer-vision, gstreamer, video-processing

I'm trying to adopt custom-made image sensor to Gstreamer pipeline with appsrc. The image sensor has resolution of 4800x2400 pixels. Now I'm stuck with problem when I can't make gstreamer work with, but every time it crashes. I'm suspect that there is some limitations that not explicit well.
So the idea is got buffer from image sensor using it's driver as unsigned char* buffer and pass it Gstreamer's appsrc with push-buffer signal. Code running on linux machine with Ubuntu22, gstreamer version is 1.20.3, g++ version is 11.3.0

I was tried the simplest pipeline that may be posiible.
Here it is:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v -e videotestsrc name=video_input do-timestamp=true ! video/x-raw, width=640, height=480, format=I420, framerate=25/1 ! xvimagesink`

This gives me window and test pattern as expected.
Then I changed to pipeline to desired resolution:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v -e videotestsrc name=video_input do-timestamp=true ! video/x-raw, width=4800, height=2400, format=I420, framerate=25/1 ! xvimagesink`

And again got test pattern but just scaled to window resolution.
Then I use the same in c++:

```
const gint mWidth = 640; //   4800; 640 1280  1920 2560 3840 // max working: 2560
const gint mHeight = 480; //  2400; 480  720  1080 1440 2160 // max working: 2100
const unsigned int mFps = 25;
const int mSize = mWidth * mHeight * 1.5;
const int frame_count = mFps * 10;
const char* mFilename = "./output_file.mp4";

typedef struct _CustomData {
    GstElement *video_appsrc;
    GMainLoop *main_loop;
    GstElement *pipeline;
    bool _need_video_;
    unsigned int video_frame;
} CustomData;

gboolean video_push_data (CustomData *data) {
    GstFlowReturn ret;
    GstBuffer *buffer;
    static int video_timestamp = 0;
    GstMapInfo info;

    buffer = gst_buffer_new_and_alloc(mSize);

    char buf[mSize];

    for(int i = 0; i < mSize; i++)
        buf[i] = rand()%255;

    gst_buffer_map(buffer, &info, GST_MAP_WRITE);

    memmove(info.data, buf, mSize);
    info.size = mSize;

    GST_BUFFER_PTS (buffer) = video_timestamp;
    GST_BUFFER_DURATION (buffer) = gst_util_uint64_scale_int (1, GST_SECOND, mFps);
    GST_BUFFER_TIMESTAMP (buffer) = gst_util_uint64_scale (data->video_frame, GST_SECOND, mFps);
    GST_BUFFER_DTS(buffer) = data->video_frame;

    video_timestamp += GST_BUFFER_DURATION (buffer);

    gst_buffer_unmap(buffer, &info);
    data->video_frame++;

    g_signal_emit_by_name (data->video_appsrc, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);
    gst_buffer_unref (buffer);

    if (ret != GST_FLOW_OK) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

static void video_start_feed (GstElement *source, guint size, CustomData *data) {
    printf("video need data %d times\n", data->video_quant);
    data->_need_video_ = 1;
}

static void video_stop_feed (GstElement *source, CustomData *data) {
    printf("video already got data \n");
    data->_need_video_ = 0;
}

void* GstreamerThread(void* pThreadParam)
{
    gst_debug_set_active(TRUE);
    gst_debug_set_default_threshold(GST_LEVEL_LOG);

    memset (&data, 0, sizeof (data));
    data.b = 1;
    data.d = 1;

    GstBus *bus;
    guint bus_watch_id;


    char *strPipeline = g_strdup_printf ("appsrc name=video_input do-timestamp=true ! video/x-raw, width=(int)%d, height=(int)%d, format=(string)I420, framerate=(fraction)%d/1 ! xvimagesink sync=true window-height=480 window-width=640 ", mWidth, mHeight, mFps); // NV12
    
    data.pipeline = gst_parse_launch(strPipeline, NULL);

    data.video_appsrc = gst_bin_get_by_name((GstBin *)(data.pipeline), "video_input");
    if( !data.video_appsrc) exit(-2);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data.video_appsrc), "is-live",    1,                             NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data.video_appsrc), "leaky-type", GST_APP_LEAKY_TYPE_DOWNSTREAM, NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data.video_appsrc), "block",      1,                             NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data.video_appsrc), "blocksize",  mSize,                         NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data.video_appsrc), "max-bytes",  mSize,                         NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data.video_appsrc), "format",     GST_FORMAT_TIME,               NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data.video_appsrc), "stream-type", 0,                            NULL); // stream
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data.video_appsrc), "duration",   GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,           NULL);

    g_object_set(G_OBJECT (data.video_appsrc), "max-time",    -1,                          NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT (data.video_appsrc), "max-latency", -1,                          NULL);

    g_signal_connect (data.video_appsrc, "need-data", G_CALLBACK (video_start_feed), &data);
    g_signal_connect (data.video_appsrc, "enough-data", G_CALLBACK (video_stop_feed), &data);

    gst_element_set_base_time( data.video_appsrc, GstClockTime(0));
    gst_element_set_start_time(data.video_appsrc, GstClockTime(0));

    data.main_loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);

    bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus(GST_PIPELINE(data.pipeline));
    bus_watch_id = gst_bus_add_watch(bus, reinterpret_cast<GstBusFunc>(bus_call), &data);

    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus), "message::error", (GCallback)error_cb, &data);

    fprintf(stderr, "Setting g_main_loop_run to GST_STATE_PLAYING\n");
    gst_element_set_state(data.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    g_main_loop_run(data.main_loop);

    fprintf(stderr, "g_main_loop_run returned, stopping playback\n");
    gst_element_set_state(data.pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

    fprintf(stderr, "Deleting pipeline\n");
    gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(data.pipeline));

    g_source_remove (bus_watch_id);
    g_main_loop_unref (data.main_loop);

    return NULL;
}

bool StartGstreamer()
{
    unsigned long GtkThreadId;
    pthread_attr_t GtkAttr;

    int result = pthread_attr_init(&GtkAttr);
    if (result != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_attr_init returned error %d\n", result);
        return false;
    }

    void* pParam = NULL;
    result = pthread_create(&GtkThreadId, &GtkAttr,
                            GstreamerThread, pParam);
    if (result != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_create returned error %d\n", result);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

gboolean bus_call(GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, CustomData *data)
{
    GMainLoop *loop = (GMainLoop *) data;

    switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg))
    {

        case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
            fprintf(stderr, "End of stream\n");
            g_main_loop_quit(loop);
            break;


        case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
        {
            gchar *debug;
            GError *error;

            gst_message_parse_error(msg, &error, &debug);
            g_free(debug);

            g_printerr("Error: %s\n", error->message);
            g_error_free(error);

            gst_element_set_state (data->pipeline, GST_STATE_READY);
            g_main_loop_quit(loop);
        }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

static void error_cb (GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, CustomData *data) {
    GError *err;
    gchar *debug_info;

    gst_message_parse_error (msg, &err, &debug_info);
    g_printerr ("Error received from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), err->message);
    g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
    g_clear_error (&err);
    g_free (debug_info);

    g_main_loop_quit (data->main_loop);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    data.video_frame = 0;
    data._need_video_ = 0;

    gst_init(NULL, NULL);

    StartGstreamer();

    while(1){
        if(data._need_video_){
            usleep(10);
            video_push_data(&data);
            printf("processing %d frame \n", data.video_frame);
        }
        else
            usleep(100);

        if(data.video_frame == frame_count)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This example code should generate white noise video in `video_push_data` method and shows it on screen just for test. And it does with resolution like 640x480 and bigger - the maximum I had got 2560x2100, but if I set 4800x2400 - the code fails once `video_push_data` has been called.
I think there is something wrong with this code or with gstreamer. I strongly suspect appsrc module, but there is no information about maximum resolution that working with.

Please help me and thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure its not related to the hard-coded size in `xvimagesink`? I would start with `fakesink` and make sure that works, and then try the `xvimagesink` again but without a set resolution (like in the `videotestsrc` pipeline you used).

Comment: Thanks for reply, but have you had change resolution from 640x480 to 4800x2400 in the beginning? There is mWidth and mHeight defined in global scope; I can't make it work either with xvimagesink nor fakesink. The hardcoded xvimagesink values is for fitting computer screen when I was debugging. My screen resolution is only 1920x1080 so xvimagesink should scale video anyway if I sets 2560x2100 and it works but if I set 4800x2400 it fails on first attemt to call `video_push_data` on reason: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Comment: If fakesink doesn't work, then your problem is elsewhere (not related to the sink).